# CSS to hide <input type="file"> not hiding the border

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im creating an app using jquery mobile and I have a feature that allows the user to click on an image which opens up

`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="submitForm(this)" capture="camera" class="hideme" accept="image/*" />`

This is working well, however, I need the input box to be hidden. I have written the following code:

```
.hideme
 { 
 display:none; 
 visibility:hidden; 
 border: 0px;
 }
```

but all this does is hide the text within the box, it doesn't actually hide the outline. Any ideas on how I can get rid of this? js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DLC4Y/

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if its not working i'll update it

Comment: why `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` in same class ?

Comment: `display : none` should be enough! Be sure u'r not overwriting the CSS somewhere else (http://jsfiddle.net/D9T6v/)

Comment: please see my jsfiddle - I added it to the original question

Comment: jQuery mobile, appends a `<div>` element to your `<input>` field. The border comes from that div element and not your input. So you need to remove this `<div>`. check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLC4Y/1/)

Use this,

```
$('#file').parent().hide();
```

jQuery mobile, appends a `<div>` element to your `<input>` field. The border comes from that div element and not your input. So you need to remove this `<div>`

OR

Add this to CSS.

**[CSS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLC4Y/2/)**

```
.ui-input-text{
    display:none; 

}
```

Comment: hello - how can i say that i want to change the .ui-input-text but only for #file? I know stupid question!

Comment: you dont have a `parent` selector in CSS. you have to use jQUery there

Comment: when I use this $('#file').parent().hide(); it is also hiding the image in my form :(

Comment: can u provide full html

Comment: I got it working, I wrapped #file in a div. Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

`display: none;` should be sufficient - it hides the element completely, including borders.

This is what I use, I have no visual or technical issues:

```
<style>
.hide-me { display: none; }
.i-am-a-link { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

<label for="image-upload" class="i-am-a-link">
    <img src="placeholder.jpg"
         id="image-upload-label">
</label>

<input type="file" id="image-upload" class="hide-me">
```

Comment: Correct, not sure why everyone is trying to hide the border when nothing is visibile and the element is not taking any space in the DOM...

Comment: this doesn't hide anything, not even the text.

Comment: Use a CSS inspector to see which rules are applied on your input...
This solution is correct

Comment: have a look at the jsfiddle i added to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`border: 0px;`

this is what you are mentioning

where as it should be

`border: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not overriding the CSS in another part of the file, also you should probably be using

```
border: none;
```

You could also possibly use the `!important` on it to override any CSS that changes the property later on.

```
border: none !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

Remove your previous styles related to `hideme` class (i.e `.hideme`) and add the following class.

```
.ui-body-c, .ui-overlay-c{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Have a nice day.